# Open file from history in Zathura

Tags: shell-script, zathura

Is this possible using a built-in command? AFAIK, it is not, so I am trying to define a mapping that uses the `exec` Zathura command to achieve this. In `bash`,

```
cat ~/.local/share/zathura/history | grep -Po "\[\K[^\]]*" | dmenu | xargs zathura
```

does the job, but I haven't managed to get this command working when using the `exec` command in Zathura. In fact, something as simple as

```
:exec ls | dmenu
```

doesn't work either, even when I surround `ls | dmenu` with quotation marks. So a more general question would be: how do I run a command with pipes from within Zathura?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this does the trick (almost, because `<cr>` still has to be pressed to execute):

```
map H feedkeys ":exec sh -c \"cat ~/.local/share/zathura/history | grep -Po '\[\K[^\]]*' | dmenu | xargs zathura\""
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh

options='-columns 6 -width 100 -lines 15 -bw 2 -yoffset -2 -location 1'

selected=$(\
        cat ~/.local/share/zathura/history | grep -Po '\[\K[^\]]*' \
        | rofi -dmenu -i -markup-rows \
        ${options} 
        )

# exit if nothing is selected
[[ -z $selected ]] && exit

zathura "$selected"

exit 0
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to explain what it’s doing?

Answer (score 2):

For me recent files works with built in "open" command.

Try type `:open /` and then hit tab. It should display "Recent files"

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and the OP will need to type-copy command examples when trying to apply your solution. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks.
Ok, I removed screenshot. Although it wasn't console output, it was screenshot of zathura UI.